# Changing only one value in configparser Python 3

Tags: python, config, configparser

I have config.ini file that is edited by multiple Python scripts simultaneously and I am facing large issue here because when updating, some values get restored and it messes up everything...
I can't use

```
config.read("config.ini")
```

every time I need to update one value because high HDD activity causes scripts to not be synchronised, and after few loop passes everything collapses again.

So, how do I change only one value?

Comment: Sounds like you're using a config file for something other than its intended purpose -- so the fix might be use something else that better supports concurrency and frequent updates.

Answer (score 0):

Ok either you want to use a database instead of a config file or you need to use stat to see if a file has been modified or you want to use inotify.
Pyinotify can detect if there is a filechange and alert through an event.

For examples see the [Pyinotify website](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/)